# The (matrix) definition of a positive-definite function

Tags: real-analysis, definition, motivation

In the [definition of a positive-definite function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function), why are the elements of the n$\times$n matrix chosen as $f(x_i-x_j)$ for $i, j = 1,...,n$?

Also, it says that "for any real numbers $x_i$". Does this mean that this works only for functions that are defined over the entire $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Why would "any real numbers" imply continuity?

Comment: @filmor since the function has to be defined for all real numbers?

Comment: As long as you're not hanging out in $L$ spaces that has nothing to do with each other. As the function is supposed to be $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ it has to be defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for considering $f(x_i-x_j)$ is stated just below on the same page: [Bochner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem), which characterizes such functions as Fourier transforms of positive measures. This is the result that motivates the definition.

The kernel of the Fourier transform, namely  the exponential function $e(x,t)=e^{-2\pi ix t}$, has the property that 
$$
e(x_i-x_j,t) = e(x_i ,t)\overline{e(x_j,t)}
$$
Hence,  the matrix with entries $e(x_i-x_j,t)$ is of the form $vv^*$ where $ v $ is the column vector with entries $e(x_i,t)$. This implies that the matrix is positive semidefinite.

Since positive semidefinite matrices form a convex cone, one half of Bochner's theorem readily follows: the Fourier transform of any   positive measure is a positive-definite function. (The converse is the hard part of the theorem.)

---

The concept is not a natural one  for functions that are defined only on a subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$. Its root is in the additive group structure of $\mathbb{R}$, which finite intervals do not have. It makes sense to consider it for functions on additive subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$, such as $\mathbb{Z}$. Or even on [more general groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function_on_a_group).

Comment: But does this apply to other functions than the Fourier transform then? Or is there some connection between approximating functions using Fourier series and positive-definite functions then?

Comment: @mavavilj Yes, there is a connection: see [this paper by Schmetterer](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-06/S0002-9939-1965-0200674-3/S0002-9939-1965-0200674-3.pdf). Generally, if you'd like to know if concepts A and B are related, Google search "A" "B" often helps.