# Ask the definition on non-negative definite function

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, analysis

The definition in my textbook is:

> A complex-valued function $f(\lambda)$ is said to be non-negative
> definite if for any $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_r$, the matrix F with
> entries $ F_{kl}= f(\lambda_k - \lambda_l)$ is non-negative definite,
> that is
>
> $(Fv,v) = \sum_{k,l= 1}^r (f(\lambda_k-\lambda_l)v_k \bar{v_l})\ge0$ for any complex vector $v_1,..., v_r$.

I feel difficult to interpret this definition. What is the relationship between $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_r$ and  $v_1,..., v_r$?

My final goal is to prove $\cos(\lambda^2)$ is non-negative definite. But before doing that, I need to make sure I understand the definition first.

Comment: There is a typo in the question, a misplaced inequality sign

Comment: @YuvalPeres updated.

Comment: "for any $\lambda_1$..." and "for any complex vector "$v_1$... " There is no relationship between the $\lambda_i$ and the $v_j$.  Two good posts are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1419692/949989) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/62991/340165).

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks. This question is closed and I asked a new relevant question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563750/how-can-i-see-the-complex-exponential-function-eiat-is-non-negative-definit

Comment: BTW questions can be edited to make them more specific.