# How can I see the complex exponential function $e^{iat}$ is non-negative definite?

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, complex-numbers

For every $a\in\mathbb R$, the complex exponential function $e^{iat}$ is non-negative definite. Why? I am not good at complex numbers.

The definition of non-negative in my textbook is:

> A complex-valued function $f(\lambda)$ is said to be non-negative
> definite if for any $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_r$, the matrix F with
> entries $ F_{kl}= f(\lambda_k - \lambda_l)$ is non-negative definite,
> that is $(Fv,v) = \sum_{k,l= 1}^r (f(\lambda_k-\lambda_l)v_k \bar{v_l})\ge0$ for any complex vector $v_1,..., v_r$.

My goal is to  prove $\cos(\lambda^2)$ is non-negative definite. To prove that, I need to prove for every $a\in\mathbb R$, the complex exponential function $e^{iat}$ is non-negative definite.

My attempt:

given this complex exponential function,

$$(Fv, v) = \sum_{k,l= 1}^r e^{ia (\lambda_k - \lambda_l)} v_k \bar{v_l}$$

$$= \sum_{k,l= 1}^r e^{ia\lambda_k} e^{-ia \lambda_l} v_k \bar{v_l}$$

$$= \sum_{k,l= 1}^r e^{ia\lambda_k} \bar{e^{ia \lambda_l}}  v_k \bar{v_l}  $$

Then how to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
 \sum_{k,l= 1}^r e^{ia\lambda_k} \bar{e^{ia \lambda_l}}  v_k \bar{v_l}
&=\Big(\sum_{k= 1}^r e^{ia\lambda_k}v_k\Big)\Big(\sum_{l= 1}^r e^{-ia\lambda_l}\overline{v_l}\Big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\Big(\sum_{k= 1}^r e^{ia\lambda_k}v_k\Big)\overline{\Big(\sum_{l= 1}^r 
e^{ia\lambda_l}{v_l}\Big)}\\[0.3cm]
&=\Big|\sum_{k= 1}^r e^{ia\lambda_k}v_k\Big|^2\geq0.
\end{align}

Comment: How to get the second line?

Comment: The conjugate is additive and multiplicative.